# Selenium Grid2 and Junit:Need suggestion regarding moving existing automation project to selenium grid for parallel execution

Tags: selenium-grid2

In my current project, we have already developed test scripts with junit framework. We have used all sort of locators methods which includes xpath as well.Now we have to do parallel execution on IE8,IE9 and FF21.We implemented grid2  with junit but we see that majority of the scripts are failing due to time out.

What I would like to know is if we have to execute 100 test cases on 5 nodes:
1.what is minimum hardware configuration required in terms of RAM,and JVM configuration
2.What is ideal hub/node configuration
3.What desired capabilities have to be set?
4.what is the best approach to set wait methods for elements and messages?

Has anyone successfully implemented selenium grid2 and ran more than 100 test cases in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Here goes my question, Have you ever executed those 100 test cases in sequence with out any such timeout issues? If yes, then you can do it in grid as well.For this, you may need minimum of 4 GB RAM and better clocked CUP. JVM version can be the same in which your scripts are done.

In general, you may need to handle some run time behavior of your application.